# mousePressed to for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I haven't coded in a long time and I'm pretty rusted.
I'm doing a project in which I need to draw a bunch of flight paths from JSON files. For testing, I created this mouse pressed function but I want to automate the process and have the flight path drawn once the previous one is done.
I assume I would need nested for loops for it to work but I'm having issues coming up with the loop structure

```
function mousePressed() {
    if (flightSelector < flightArray[daySelector].length - 1) {
        flightSelector++;
        console.log(flightSelector);
    } else {
        flightSelector = 0
        if (daySelector < dayArray.length - 1) {
            daySelector++;
        }
    }
    getFlightData(dayArray[daySelector], flightArray[daySelector][flightSelector]);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic scenario for a pair of nested loops. You are running some code repeatedly for each day, and for each day you are running it repeatedly for each flight that happened that day:

```
for (let daySelector = 0; daySelector < dayArray.length; daySelector++) {
  for (let flightSelector = 0; flightSelector < flightArray[daySelector].length; flightSelector++) {
    getFlightData(dayArray[daySelector], flightArray[daySelector][flightSelector]);
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not working, it is cycling over and over the same segment

Comment: You'll need to provide a reproducible example of that issue.

Comment: unless I provide you with the entire repo I dunno how I can do that.
what if I rename the function mousePressed to something else and use that in the for loop?